# PHP Laravel Nova How to save Multiselect values in DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using [this](https://github.com/arku31/NovaMultiSelect) multiselect plugin for my `Laravel` nova application and so far it works ok, but when I save the selected options in my DB, it only saves the ID, but I would rather to save the name of the option (or both)

Here is my code

```
use Nova\Multiselect\Multiselect;

return [
   Multiselect::make('Favorites', 'favorites')->options($this->getFavoriteOptions())
]

public static function getFavoriteOptions()
{
    return Favorite::all()->pluck('name');
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
//use get() instead of pluck() try this


use Nova\Multiselect\Multiselect;

return [
   Multiselect::make('Favorites', 'favorites')->options($this->getFavoriteOptions())
]

public static function getFavoriteOptions()
{
    return Favorite::all()->get();
}
```

Comment: hmm, this returns `[Object Object]` :-s

Comment: Can you explain what this code does? Should this be included in a class?